# Cant instantiate a class in c++, memory error

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;



class Datei {

public:
    Datei();
    ~Datei();

    void Datei::DataInput(int i);

private:

    string name = 0;
    int number = 0;
    string date = 0;


};
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: every time i get this exception: Exception thrown at 0x585ED6F0 (ucrtbased.dll) in Sortieren und Filehandling.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Why are you setting the strings `name` and `date` to 0 ?

Comment: Please post code that actually compiles, or if the problem is that it does not, post the compiler error. At least provide a decent description of your problem and what you have attempted. :)

Comment: You forgot to post your code. What is `Sortieren`?. You only posted some header file.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number a errors in your code, you should go back and check how classes are defined.

Remember to only use default values for your members in an initializer inline if no constructors assign different value than those. Then you should use an initializer list in the constructors

Besides you can't set a string to `0`, it should be `""`. Strings are by default set to "", so there is no need to specify a value.
So the declaration of the class would be

```
class Datei {

public:
    Datei() {

    }
    ~Datei() {}

    void DataInput(int i) {
        //stuff
    }

private:

    string name;
    int number = 0;
    string date;
};
```

Note that I added the implementation of the function during declaration but this can be done in your .ccp, that's up to you.

This is a simple working code that instatiates your class.

```
#include <string> // Feel free to use this if included

using namespace std;

class Datei {

public:
    Datei() {

    }
    ~Datei() {}

    void DataInput(int i) {
        //stuff
    }

private:

    string name;
    int number = 0;
    string date;
};

int main()
{
    Datei dat;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `name("")` and `date("")` are odd.

Comment: *your members should not be set default value outside of the constructor that's what it's for* it is controversial.

Comment: Edited my post since because there was a mistake. What is wrong about initializing strings this way? It worked fine on my end. I realize how inline initializer can be the right way to go, it's edited

Comment: The problem is not that it does not work @Someprogammer the problem is that you are performing an unnecessary operation, the strings are default constructed to be empty, that is what the default constructor is for, why perform the extra work of explicitly setting them to be an empty string? It's a minor note, but I agree with S.M.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, answer edited

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all, who posted a comment, especially to Some programmer ;-)

I have adapted my code now, and here's also main.cpp:

---

```
int main(){

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    Datei data;
    data.DataInput(i);
}

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class Datei {
public:
Datei()
{

}
~Datei()
{

}

void Datei::DataInput(int i)
{
    cout << "Name, Vorname:" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Zahl:" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Datum:" << endl;
    cin >> date;



}

private:



string name = "";
int number = 0;
string date = "";


};
```

Comment: and yeah, it works :)